# Eclipse and SFML2 problems (pssibly linking?) on Linux Mint

Tags: c++, eclipse, linker, sfml, 2d-games

I compiled sfml2 (latest github version) with gcc and make, and it all went fine. I'm able to compile example programs directly with g++ in the terminal, but whenever i use Eclipse it complains about undefined references to classes in the sf:: namespace.

I have set up my project  accordingly, added the /usr/local/include, /usr/local/lib, SFML_DYNAMIC symbol and the sfml-* libraries in the correct order, but it still does not compile if I don't use "using namespace sf", and even then, I still get all the errors, although I'm able to run the program.

Also, when I try and use Intellisense (or whatever it's called in Eclipse), when i type sf:: it gives me a lot of irrelevant stuff to this namespace.

I'm using Linux Mint 14, Eclipse Juno with CDT and the default linux gcc tools.

Here's a screenshot of what my IDE currently looks like:

[Eclipse IDE screenshot http://dl.dropbox.com/u/62794148/Screenshot%20from%202013-04-02%2010%3A26%3A08.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/62794148/Screenshot%20from%202013-04-02%2010%3A26%3A08.png)

Comment: the image seems to small, what exactly are you getting in terms of errors?

Comment: Eclipse cannot resolve fields or methods withing the sf namespace. Just right click on the image and open in another tab.